# How to optimize loading 150GB data into hive table?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, memory, hive, cloudera

I have a 150 GB file in hive stage table which uses following table properties

```
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
       "separatorChar" = "|",
       "quoteChar"     = "'",
       "escapeChar"    = "\\"
    )  
    STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Now when I load this data in my main table, it fails with **java heap error** after running for one hour. I am using partitioned main table and there are about 12000 partitions in the data.
For loading the data I am using simple hql:

```
    insert overwrite mainTable partition(date)
    select * from stage table;
```

I have also tried increasing the map memory to 15GB but sill it fails.
Is there any way to optimize this ?
Any solution which includes spark or hive would work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check following :
1)  Try increasing HADOOP_HEAPSIZE for hive-server2 in /etc/hive/conf/hive-env.sh
2) Restart Hive using below commands by connecting to master node to reflect changes in settings 
sudo stop hive-hcatalog-server
sudo start hive-hcatalog-server
sudo status hive-hcatalog-server

Reference : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-hive-outofmemoryerror-heap-space/

Answer (score 0):

Add `distribute by partition key`

```
insert overwrite mainTable partition(date)
    select * from stage table 
distribute by date;
```

this will trigger final reduce stage (if it runs on map-only) and each reducer will write single partition, not all of them, creating less files and using less buffers consuming less memory.

If you need more parallelism, then check bytes.per.reducer hive setting, maybe it's too high.

```
set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=67108864;
```

Also you can use distribute by partition key and random integer to distribute data evenly between more reducers: `distribute by substr(date), FLOOR(RAND()*100.0)%20`

Answer (score -1):

I think you get so many partitions in this sql task.  **java heap error** may caused by the much number of tasks.

So you can consider to create a  range partition( by month) table to reduce the num of tasks.